# jquery load method with redirected page

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have a page in which different div's are present each div has a link and on click of that link it display the content of the output page. This works fine if the output page does not redirect to any other page.
So how can I display the redirected page output in the div, is there any other method I should be using other than load?

Answer (score 0):

May be a way with ajax ?

```js
//add this on the 
$().ready(function(){
  $( "#result" ).load( "pages/yourpage.html", function() {
    console.log( "Page Loaded ..." );
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="result"> Out page html loaded here </div>
```